# Woocommerce Ajax добавление в корзину на странице каталога

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ajax работает, если перейти на страницу товара и добавить в корзину. Но шаблон таков, что перехода на страницу товара вообще нет. Есть категории, краткое описание и сразу в корзину. Как сделать так, чтобы Ajax срабатывал и там тоже?

У меня кастомные формы, у каждого товара несколько кнопок "в корзину", в зависимости от цены.

```
foreach ($variations as $variation) {

    // get variation ID
    $variation_ID = $variation->ID; 

    echo '<form method="POST" action="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() . '">
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">В корзину</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="'.$variation_ID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="'.$variation_ID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="'.$variation_ID.'">
        ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню в стандартном функционале вукоммерса это уже решено, но в целом уже есть описание того, как это реализовать кастомно в данной теме:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892871/woocommerce-product-page-how-to-create-ajax-on-add-to-cart-button